# Sencha Touch / ExtJs show XTemplate only if array node contains items

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

How can I show a an XTemplate only if the data array has items at a certain node?

For example below, I only want to show my template for "items." (show day 28's "items" and show nothing for day 27)

Currently it creates a p tag for all items in the array, which what I don't want...

```
        itemTpl     :    new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for="items">'+
                  '<p>{classname} {typename}</p>'+
                '</tpl>'
        ),
```

---

Data from the server:

```
{
  day:27,
  iscurrentmonth:false,
  issunday:false,
  date:"2013-05-27",
  schedulesection:{
     id:46694897,
     markingperiodid:15156,
     name:"Sunday",
     number:0
  },
  announcements:[

  ],
  items:[

  ]
},
 {
  day:28,
  iscurrentmonth:false,
  issunday:false,
  date:"2013-05-28",
  schedulesection:{
     id:46695811,
     markingperiodid:15156,
     name:"Monday",
     number:1
  },
  announcements:[

  ],
  items:[
     {
        id:134513,
        title:"Subject",
        typeid:3,
        typename:"Essay",
        author:"Bryan Fisher",
        classname:"English 9A",
        classid:344499,
        courseid:60555
     },
     {
        id:134485,
        title:"Subject",
        typeid:3,
        typename:"Essay",
        author:"Bryan Fisher",
        classname:"English 10",
        classid:344500,
        courseid:60555
     }
  ]
 }
```

Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not  sure if get you right, but it think is:

```
itemTpl: [
    '<tpl for="items">',
        '<tpl if="values.classname">',
            '<p>{classname} {typename}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>',
].join('')
```

hope it helps

Comment: I think he's after how to determine whether or not the context has an array of items or not.

Comment: @existdissolve is correct..  day 28 was just an example. All the data will be dynamic

Comment: got it, you r just trying to remove the empty <p></p>

Comment: Exactly.. I tried azche's example just for shts and giggles to see what happens and it still shows the blank slots.

Comment: okay so I changed the xtype to a "dataview" and it renders correctly.. but i've lost the nice "list" feel. I think I can hack it from here on out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Conditional processing with basic comparison operators" section in the `Ext.XTemplate` docs. http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

```
<tpl if="items.length">
   <tpl for="items">
      ...
   </tpl>
</tpl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried many different iterations of this, and still isn't working the way I'm going for. It always the "blank slots" for the other data items